# SqlLocalDb: Why does instance show in list but am unable to delete?

Tags: localdb

If I do `sqllocaldb i` from the command line I see a list of instances as I expect, but there is one in there which I find I cannot delete nor connect to. Let's call it "troublesome".

If I try and access it using the SqlLocalDb API:

`GetInstances()` returns the same list of instances that `sqllocaldb i` does, including the troublesome one, yet `GetInstance("troublesome")` throws an exception "The SQL LocalDB instance 'troublesome' does not exist".

I can create a second instance with the same name as the troublesome one, no problems. `sqllocaldb c troublesome` works, just fine (I end up with two "troublesome" in the list), and I can delete it too. But the original one is still there.

Any clues?

Answer (score 0):

This was caused by a stray localdb registration from a previous (deleted) user account.

If you look in the registry at the following key: `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\UserInstances` you can see all the instances.

The troublesome instance was there with a `DataDirectory` path set to an invalid location.